# Scholar One Email System

Tags: publications, paper-submission, journal-workflow

I sent an email to a journal's editorial office via Scholar One's Manuscript Central. I had clicked on the EO's link , which led to a popup and then sent the mail by clicking on "Save and Send". My Question now is, where can I find the record of this email? I cannot find it in my email ID's sent folder nor does ScholarOne have one for this.

Answer (score 6):

When a journal is set up on ScholarOne, one piece of information they provide is an EO email address. When you filled out the form, ScholarOne sent the email to that address "on behalf of" you. There is no direct way for you to view this correspondence through the system. You could contact the EO office again, and ask for a copy to be forwarded to you. You could also reach out to ScholarOne support to see if they could get you a copy.

Disclaimer: I am an employee at ScholarOne, but the opinions and posts here are my own.